# Embedding text in AS2, like HEREDOC or CDATA

Tags: string, actionscript-2, multiline, cdata, heredoc

I'm loading a text file into a string variable using LoadVars(). For the final version of the code I want to be able to put that text as part of the actionscript code and assign it to the string, instead of loading it from an external file.

Something along the lines of HEREDOC syntax in PHP, or CDATA in AS3 ( http://dougmccune.com/blog/2007/05/15/multi-line-strings-in-actionscript-3/ )

Quick and dirty solutions I've found is to put the text into a text object in a movieclip and then get the value, but I dont like it

Btw: the text is multiline, and can include single quotes and double quotes.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't get why you can't use CDATA...

Comment: Not sure how to use it to do this in AS2, can you give me an example?

Comment: Aww sorry... "AS2" was the part of your question my brain refused to compute...

Comment: Graduate yourself to AS3. Really pointless to be developing anything in AS2 anymore. Take the lead and the learning curve and learn it

Comment: Thanks for your very useful comment. Unfortunately no time to rebuild everything in AS3 (including code that is not yours) when you have to deliver in a week.

Answer (score 2):

I think in AS2 the only way seems to do it dirty. In AS3 you can embed resources with the Embed tag, but as far as I know not in AS2.

If it's a final version and it means you don't want to edit the text anymore, you could escape the characters and use \n as a line break.

```
var str = "\'one\' \"two\"\nthree";
trace(str);
```

outputs:

```
'one' "two"
three
```

Now just copy the text into your favourite text editor and change every ' and " to \' and \", also the line breaks to \n.

Comment: This was the first solution that came to my mind, but I liked it even less than copy/paste into a text object. Btw: the text is long (50k+) so this would create an extremely long line. And it'd be harder to edit each time something needs to be tweaked. Thanks anyway!

Comment: No problem. You said "for the final version of the code" - meaning you don't want to change the text. Also, no matter on the length of your text this is the only solution to "embed" text as it is in a script as a variable. And as how you wanted it.

Comment: Its final on my end, but not in the clients end. They might still want to tweak something after I deliver. So I'm looking for a solution that is easy for them to modify if necessary. So far the best I've came up with was putting it into a text object, which is a nasty hack but works. But I though it was possible to do something like heredoc, which would be much better. Unfortunately it seems its not possible.

Comment: I see. If clients handle it then your solution is the best. Especially if they are no programmers or scripters. They can see the whole text in the textfield and edit it. Why is it so important to embed a 50k text in the flash, especially if it's changing? No chance to load it from an external file?

Comment: They want a single swf containing the whole thing. Btw: thanks a lot for taking the time to answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Cristian, anemgyenge's solution works when you realize it's a single line. It can be selected and replaced in a simple operation.

Don't edit the doc in the code editor. Edit the doc in a doc editor and create a process that converts it to a long string (say running it through a quick PHP script). Take the converted string and paste it in over the old string. Repeat as necessary.

It's way less than ideal from a long-term management perspective, especially if code maintenance gets handed off without you handing off the parser, but it gets around some of your maintenance issues.

Comment: Hi Greg, thanks. I used the solution I described in the question (putting the text into a movieclip) and that did the trick. Going to use AS3 from now on (until another client requires AS2). Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Use a new pair of quotes on each line and add a space as the word delimiter:

```
var foo = "Example of string " +
"spanning multiple lines " +
"using heredoc syntax."
```

There is a project which may help that adds partial E4X support to ActionScript 2:

- [as24x](http://code.google.com/p/as24x/)

As well as a project which adds E4X support to Haxe, which can compile to a JavaScript target:

- [E4X Macro for Haxe](http://www.tbyrne.org/e4x-macro-for-haxe)